# Examples of both hardware and software GNSS recievers

Tags: gps, computing, gnss, logistics

I am writing an essay titled: Critically evaluate the positional fixing capabilities of current smartphone technologies for real world GIS data collection

I am wanting examples of both hardware and software GNSS recievers.

Currently i am led to believe smart phones run software based recivers and a hand held ,garmin for example, GPS device would be a hardware reciver.

Comment: Any GPS and other satellite navigation receivers use a combination of hardware and software. A pure hardware solution is impossible, but a pure software solution too.

Comment: @Uwe while the *correlator* section will need a combination of digital processing and software/firmware, there is a wide range *possible receiver implementations* that can range from pure analog hardware to almost pure SDR ([software defined radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio)). I think the problem here is that a GNSS device has several distinct sections, and even the digital sections can be implemented using either generalized processing hardware driven by software or implemented in dedicated, optimized, application-specific hardware.

Comment: Hi @TomHaywood and *Welcome to Space!* There must be a better SE site for this question than Space Exploration but I'm not sure which one. There are [nearly 200 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) available. For example [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) has over [300 questions tagged `gps`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps) but you'd better read through questions there first to see if there are answers already or if this kind of question would be considered on-topic there.

Comment: If you think you can adjust this question to make it more about GNSS satellites, or signal propagation in space (including the ionosphere) or even GNSS usage in space, that would be great! Questions about how radios work are probably off-topic here though.

Comment: this helped my understanding of the topic thank you

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2017/05/09/a-full-stack-gps-receiver/